# Вывести DataGrid несколько раз с разными данными

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток. Очень нуждаюсь в подсказке или помощи в реализации динамического добавления DataGrid.
По идее у меня есть шаблон DataGrid, который биндиться с DataTable. Дело в том, что на странице мне необходимо отобразить несколько DataGrid, которые будут как-то методом перебора биндиться к разным DataTable и выводить мне данные  на станицу. Сколько таких таблиц будет – всё зависит от приходящих DataTable и соотв. Прописать их жестко в разметке нет смыла. Как можно добиться подобного результата. Примерный скрин, как должно получиться в результате во вложении. 
+ Необходимо, чтобы сохранялась возможность слежения за DataGrid. Т.е. если какой-то из списка отредактировали – я мог узнать какой именно редактировали и получить именно к нему доступ. 
Буду благодарен любой помощи по этой теме

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не уверен, что понимаю, что вы хотите получить

Comment: `которые будут как-то методом перебора биндиться к разным DataTable и выводить мне данные на станицу.` мне кажется, что задачу можно решить проще, чем методом перебора

Comment: btw, на мой взгляд, удобнее работать с типизированными коллекциями, чем `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это то, что вы хотели.
Пример класса, который генерирует DataGrid для отображения данных на основе коллекции DataTable

```
class DataGridBuilder
{
    private List<DataTable> _dataTables { get; set; }

    public DataGridBuilder(List<DataTable> tables)
    {
        _dataTables = tables;
    }

    public void BuildGrid(Panel controlForRendering)
    {
        _dataTables.ForEach(table => {
            var grid = new DataGrid();
            grid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;               
            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            controlForRendering.Children.Add(grid);
        });
    }
}
```

А это класс, демонстрирующий использование этого генератора

```
 private static List<DataTable> GetDataTableCollection(int dataTableCount)
    {
        var collection = new List<DataTable>();
        for(var i = 0; i < dataTableCount; i++)
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("FirstColumn");
            table.Columns.Add("SecondColumn");
            table.Columns.Add("ThirdColumn");
            for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    $"First column data {r}"
                    ,$"Second column data {r}"
                    ,$"Third column data {r}"
                });
            }
            collection.Add(table);
        }
        return collection;
    }
    public static void UseDataGridBuilder(Panel someParentControl)
    {
        var dataTableCollection = GetDataTableCollection(5);
        var dataGridBuilder = new DataGridBuilder(dataTableCollection);
        dataGridBuilder.BuildGrid(someParentControl);            
    }
}
```

Отслеживание источников данных будут производить сами гриды, правда байдинга здесь не происходит, поэтому при редактирования какой-то ячейки в гриде изменений в DataTable происходить не будет. Но в вашей ситуации этого и не требуется, насколько я понял из вашего вопроса.